# Connecting to Linkedin adAnalytics API - Unpermitted fields present in parameter

Tags: postman, linkedin-api

I am having trouble connecting to the LinkedIn AdAnalytics API. While using postman to test my connection - I receive the error:

```
{
    "serviceErrorCode": 100,
    "message": "Unpermitted fields present in PARAMETER: Data Processing Exception
                while processing fields [/daterange]",
    "status": 403
}
```

I can verify I have access. I am able to generate the access token with Oath 2.0 in postman. I used https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/marketing/getting-started to setup Oauth 2.0 access on postman and make sure I have the right permissions on my app. I am using the following scopes for my access.

```
r_organization_social, w_organization_social, rw_organization_admin,
rw_ads, r_ads_reporting, r_liteprofile
```

Here is an example of using the V2 notation https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/shared/api-guide/concepts/protocol-version?context=linkedin/marketing/context:

[image]

Here is an example of using V1 notation https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/marketing/integrations/ads-reporting/ads-reporting#sample-request.

[image]

Neither notation worked. I am very new to APIs so I am sure I am missing something, but I am unsure what it is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you can see [in the example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/marketing/integrations/ads-reporting/ads-reporting#sample-request), you can pass the dateRange values as single params in query string as follow:

```
CAMPAIGN&dateRange.start.day=1&dateRange.start.month=1&dateRange.start.year=2017&timeGranularity=DAILY
```

**EDIT**: Take care of use the camelCase version of the params name, in detail for dateRange: replace `daterange` with `dateRange` in all the occurrences and retry (I've replicated the error using the version in lowercase)

Hope this help

Comment: Thanks Matteo, unfortunately this does not work either. I will add screenshot to my post above.

Comment: Hi @Jimbo try with the camelCase version: use dateRange instead of daterange

Comment: @Jimbo see my update: use the camelCase version of the dateRange field

Comment: perfect! It was my camelCase. Thank you for figuring this out. I am running into another error saying "missing facet", which I believe means there is no data. if you have any insight on this too?

Comment: in case of no data seems return an empty array. Can you share more context (the request you made) preferably in a new question?

Comment: This does not work with version 2 of LinkedIn `Rest.li` protocol for analytics.
So if you specify in the request headers: `X-Restli-Protocol-Version: 2.0.0` and in the request params `?q: analytics` this will not work.