# Linkedin Ads API What's the format of the `dateRange` request parameter?

Tags: rest, linkedin-api

What's the right format for dateRange for `rest-li` v2?
The current examples in the documentation do not support it, and I don't understand from the `rest-li` documentation what's the format for it, exactly.

## This is the request I make:

#### Headers:

- `X-Restli-Protocol-Version: 2.0.0`
- `Authorization: Bearer <token-here>`

#### URL (with request parameters):

https://api.linkedin.com/v2/adAnalyticsV2?q=analytics&pivot=CAMPAIGN&dateRange.start.day=1&dateRange.start.month=1&dateRange.start.year=2017&timeGranularity=DAILY

#### OR

#### URL - deconstructed (with request parameters):

- Base URL:`https://api.linkedin.com/v2`
- Params:

  - `q:analytics`
  - `pivot:CAMPAIGN`
  - `dateRange.start.day:1`
  - `dateRange.start.month:1`
  - `dateRange.start.year:2017`
  - `timeGranularity:DAILY`

## Error I get:

> ```
> {
>    "serviceErrorCode": 100,
>    "message": "Unpermitted fields present in PARAMETER: Data Processing >Exception while processing fields [/dateRange.start.day, /dateRange.start.month, >/dateRange.start.year]",
>    "status": 403
> }
> ```

Note: I'm referred to a question with the same error in the comments, however this might be caused by a different reason, and the answer there does not work for me. If by StackOverflow's standards you still think that it's a duplicate, please let me know and I'll close this question.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57957853/connecting-to-linkedin-adanalytics-api-unpermitted-fields-present-in-parameter

Comment: Not all the endpoint work in the same manner, do you have one or more  endpoints you need to paginate?

Comment: @Matteo I most likely have multiple ones (I have specification for what data to request from the API, not sure which endpoints I need just yet).

But this is a very specific problem, how's that relevant, in your opinion, to my question?

Comment: @codebrane the answer in that question does not work for me, check my answer there. Could be a matter of a specific endpoint needing a specific format as Matteoo said but I don't know how I could verify that.

Comment: Hi! @GalGrünfeld does linkedin API has a way to get ad spend data for a given account in a given date range with one API call. instead of getting campaigns for an account and fetching data for each one iteratively

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution provided by one of the LinkedIn developers:

For Restli version 2, for parameter `dateRange` (tested only for endpoint `AnalyticsV2`):

- `rangeDate := (start[,end])` (`end` is optional)
- `start`, `end` - type: `Date`
- `Date := (day, month, year)`

  - `day` - type: `integer` (tested for single digit only)
  - `month` - type: `integer` (tested for single digit only)
  - `year` - type: `integer` (tested for 4 digits only)

Final structure (not including the optional `end`):
dateRange=(start:(day:,month:,year:))

Example:
`dateRange=(start:1,month:1,year:2017)`

Comment: This didn't work for me. I'm sending https://api.linkedin.com/v2/adAnalyticsV2?q=analytics&pivot=ACCOUNT&timeGranularity=DAILY&dateRange=%28start%3A%28day%3A1%2Cmonth%3A1%2Cyear%3A2020%29%29 (start:(day:1,month:1,year:2020)) and i'm getting {"message":"Parameter 'dateRange' is invalid","status":400}

Comment: Anyone ever figure this out, having same issue?

Comment: I think you guys should talk to them directly, because that solution was given me by one of their developers, and I tested it and it worked for me at the time..

Comment: What integer does LinkedIn used for the month here? Wound month `1` be January or February?

Answer (score 5):

The first solution didn't work for me. As Linkedin's API documentation is shit in regards to this it took me a lot of trial and error. @Gal-Grünfeld final structure is correct but the example isn't. Linkedin's docs say the key is `dateRange.start` which is wrong.

```
dateRange=(start:(day:1,month:9,year:2020))
```

Comment: Same error w/ the above - is something wrong in my url? 

url = 'https://api.linkedin.com/v2/adAnalyticsV2?q=analytics&dateRange=(start:(day:1,month:9,year:2019))&dateRange=(start:(day:1,month:9,year:2019))&accounts=urn%3Ali%3AsponsoredAccount%3A435225479&pivot=MEMBER_COMPANY&projection=(*,elements*(externalWebsiteConversions,dateRange(*),impressions,landingPageClicks,likes,shares,costInLocalCurrency,approximateUniqueImpressions,pivot,pivotValue~(localizedName)))&fields=externalWebsiteConversions,dateRange,impressions,landingPageClicks,likes,shares,costInLocalCurrency,pivot,pivotValue'

Answer (score 2):

When you are using Python and requests, the working format of 'dateRange' parameter is:

```
    params = {
        'q': 'analytics',
        'dateRange.start.day': '1',
        'dateRange.start.month': '1',
        'dateRange.start.year': '2022',
        'pivot': 'COMPANY',
        'timeGranularity': 'DAILY'
        }
```

But remember to remove (or not use at all) the header "X-Restli-Protocol-Version"

Answer (score 0):

Be careful about the query parameter encoding, I am using Faraday library for HTTP get requests and it encodes the query string, so I am correctly using the dateRange=(start:(day:1,month:9,year:2020)), but at the end Faraday encodes it to something like this: dateRange%3D%28start%3A%28day%3A1%2Cmonth%3A9%2Cyear%3A2020%29%29. But linkedin expects the first brackets unencoded, I had same problem with other endpoint, where the List(something) was not working, but with curl it was working, the difference is encoding.