# Unpermitted fields present in PARAMETER when pulling ad analytics

Tags: linkedin-api

I get a 403 Forbidden response along with the `"serviceErrorCode":100,"message":"Unpermitted fields present in PARAMETER: Data Processing Exception while processing f (truncated...)` error when running this get request:

```
https://api.linkedin.com/v2/adAnalyticsV2?q=analytics&pivot=ACCOUNT&timeGranularity=DAILY&dateRange.start.day=22&dateRange.start.month=09&dateRange.start.year=2020&dateRange.end.day=22&dateRange.end.month=10&dateRange.end.year=2020&accounts%5B0%5D=urn%3Ali%3AsponsoredAccount%3A248XXXXXXXXX&fields=costInUsd,externalWebsiteConversions,impressions,clicks,conversionValueInLocalCurrency&start=0&count=500
```

I verified that i have the `rw_ads` and `r_ads_reporting` permissions.

Anybody know what this could be?

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out. The dateRange is wrong. It needs to be:

`dateRange=(start:(day:1,month:9,year:2020))`

As Linkedin's API documentation is shit in regards to this it took me a lot of trial and error. I found a partial answer on this stackoverlow [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60436604/linkedin-ads-api-whats-the-format-of-the-daterange-request-parameter). The final structure is correct but the example isn't. Linkedin's docs say the key is `dateRange.start` which is wrong.